# Eigenvectors of this matrix - what's the relation to rotation operator?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, diagonalization

[image]

I have found the eigenvalues to be 0, 1 and 2.

The corresponding eigenvectors are: $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (1 , -1, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1, 1, 0)$.

I found that when $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ was expressed in $x^T A x$.

So, to diagonalize A, the diagonalizing matrix is made up of columns of eigenvectors which turns out to be the rotation matrix, rotating about z-axis.

Then I found the rotation angle $\theta = 45^o$.

But when i find diagonalized form $x^TA'x = 2y'^2 + z'^2 = 1$. This is strange.

Comment: Incidentally, the rotation operator has little to do with the quadratic form, except that it reveals the true nature of the form. In other words, you could take a different quadratic form and if it was rotated off the standard form in the same way then you'd find the same set of eigencoordinates. The eigenvalues are tied to the true nature of the form, but the eigenvectors can be shared by other forms with entirely different spectra (set of e-values).

Comment: This is an extruded surface because $A$ as a non-trivial null space. So there is a direction ($(1,-1,0)$ in this case) that does not enter into the expression for the value of the form $x^{T}Ax$. The equation $x^{T}Ax=1$ only involves the other two variables, which reduces this to an extruded surface.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you diagonalize $Q: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ you find
$Q(x',y',z') =  \lambda_1(x')^2+\lambda_2(y')^2+\lambda_3(z')^2$. This is what you found. However, $\lambda_1=0$ so that term appears to be absent.

Geometrically, you have an elliptical cylinder where $x'$ is the axis-coordinate.

**Added in response to comment:** Consider,
$$ x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + z^2 = 1$$
simplifies to:
$$ (x + y)^2 + z^2 = 1$$
But, we must divide and multiply by two to pick up an orthonormal coordinate change:
$$ 2\left(\frac{x + y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + z^2 = 1$$
Then, as $y' = \frac{x + y}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $z=z'$ we obtain your formula. On the other hand, $x' =\frac{x - y}{\sqrt{2}}$ does not appear nontrivially in the quadratic form.
I can get into the matrix of the coordinate change if need be, I'm not sure what more to say here, the $\lambda=0,2$ e-vectors are in the $xy$-plane whereas $\lambda=1$ corresponds to the $z$-axis which serves as the rotation axis for the coordinate change in question. Furthermore, if you look at your first and third e-vectors it can be seen those are a rotation by $45^o$ in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: That is what I have found, but what bothers me is that the rotation matrix is in the x-y plane